# fread y fwrite con punteros dobles en c

Tags: c, archivo, punteros

Estoy intentado escribir un array de estrucutas a un archivo binario  pero cuando llamo la funcion fwrite no guarda nada en el fichero.

Edito: agrego la definición de Pagina

```
typedef struct Pagina Pagina;
struct Pagina
{
  char *Instrucción;
  char *register1;
  char *register2;
};


void Escribir_swap(const char *PCB, const char *Archivo, Pagina **Paginas){
FILE *A, *B;
char exeption[5] = " \n\t,";
char LINE[LONG_MAX_LINE];
int TAM = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < MARCOS; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < PAGINAS; j++){
        if(Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A) !=NULL ){
            Paginas[i][j].Instruccion = strdup(Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A));
            Paginas[i][j].register1 = strdup(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 1));
            Paginas[i][j].register2 = strdup(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 2));
            TAM++;
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
      }
    }
printf("I\t R1,R2\n");
for(i = 0; i<MARCOS; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<PAGINAS; j++)
    {
            printf("%s\t %s,%s\n", Paginas[i][j].Instruccion, Paginas[i][j].register1, Paginas[i][j].register2);
    }
}
if(B = fopen(Archivo, "wb")==NULL)
{

    printf("Error al abrir archivo %s", Archivo);
    perror(Archivo);
}else
{
    for(i = 0; i<MARCOS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<PAGINAS;j++)
        fwrite(&Paginas[i][j], sizeof(Pagina), 1, B);
    }
}
fflush(B);
fclose(B);
}
```

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieses la declaración de `Pagina`

Comment: Ya edite, aun que al agregar los datos a la estructura funciona bien, el ciclo de abajo muestro el resultado y se guarda bien

Answer (score 1):

Si asumimos que estás compilando en 32 bits (por ejemplo) y hacemos:

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(Pagina));
```

Por pantalla aparecerá el número 12. Es decir, la estructura ocupará 12 bytes en memoria. ¿Cómo es posible que ocupe únicamente 12 bytes si puedes, por ejemplo, almacenar el quijote entero en `Instruccion`?

El problema aquí es que la estructura utiliza punteros en vez de arrays de tamaño fijo:

```
struct Pagina
{
  char Instruccion[10];
  char register1[10];
  char register2[10];
};
```

Y por este motivo la estructura contiene únicamente direcciones de memoria... no contiene ni un solo dato válido. Los datos se encuentran en vete tu a saber qué parte de la memoria.

Ignoro los requisitos de la aplicación, por lo que te toca a tí asignar el tamaño concreto a cada array, pero la estructura debería parecerse más a la que te he puesto 2 párrafos antes. Eso sí, al hacer esto ya no podrás hacer asignaciones:

```
Paginas[i][j].Instruccion = strdup(Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A));
Paginas[i][j].register1 = strdup(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 1));
Paginas[i][j].register2 = strdup(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 2));
```

Porque un array de tamaño fijo no es un puntero que se pueda reasignar... ahora tendrías que copiar las cadenas:

```
strcpy(Get_I(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A),Paginas[i][j].Instruccion);
strcpy(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 1),Paginas[i][j].register1);
strcpy(Get_R(TAM, PCB, LINE, exeption, A, 2),Paginas[i][j].register2);
```

Comment: Hice el cambio pero aun me da fallo de segmentacion a la hora de escribir en el archivo con la funcion fwrite.

Comment: @JuanJ.Mart sin conocer la declaración de `Paginas` es complicado decirte posibles motivos